# Insert a record Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

So I was trying to insert a record in a database using entity Framework well I tried this simple code

```
TestEntities DB = new TestEntities();
List<Article> Articles = BD.Articles.ToList();
Articles.Add(new Article() { Id = 0, Category = "Category1",  Title = "Title1"});
Articles.Add(new Article() { Id = 0, Category = "Category2", Title = "Title2" });
DB.SaveChanges();
```

The records got added to the Articles list but not to the database can someone please explain to me how does this work.

Comment: You're adding items into `Articles` list, not to your context. Try `BD.Articles.Add(...)` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Articles` is just an in-memory copy of the `DbSet`. You should add the items to the `DbSet` as well if you want to be able to persist them to the database:

```
var art = new Article() { Id = 0, Category = "Category1",  Title = "Title1"};
Articles.Add(art);
BD.Articles.Add(art);
```

The `List<Article>` is not "connected" to the `DbSet`, `DbContext` nor the database in any way.

Comment: Fair enough, I though its somehow a list of references and editing it would mean editing the db.Articles.

Answer (score 0):

```
using(TestEntities DB = new TestEntities())
{
    BD.Articles.Add(new Article() { Id = 0, Category = "Category1",  Title = "Title1"});
    BD.Articles.Add(new Article() { Id = 0, Category = "Category2", Title = "Title2" });
    DB.SaveChanges();
}
```

1. Add the new article to the DbSet, not the retrieved List which is just an in memory representation.
2. Always wrap your types that implement IDisposable in `using` statements. In this case it ensures that the db connection is closed when the code exists.